# Error while trying to run 32-bit app on 64-bit. Running with sudo works fine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm, glibc, arm64

I have compiled a simple hello-world application on 32-bit arm machine. And copied the required 32-bit libs onto the aarch64 machine.(ld-2.19.so  and libc-2.19.so)

Runs fine if I am a root (sudo), but permission denied for normal users.

Here's the error -

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./ld-2.19.so ./hello_world 
./hello_world: error while loading shared libraries: ./hello_world: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./ld-2.19.so --list ./hello_world 
./hello_world: error while loading shared libraries: ./hello_world: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

Here's the behaviour with sudo-

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ./ld-2.19.so ./hello_world
Hello World
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ./ld-2.19.so --list ./hello_world
linux-vdso32.so.1 =>  (0xf75cd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xf74de000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => ./ld-2.19.so (0xaae03000)
```

Comment: Off-topic, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I don't think it is off topic. Did you check kernel log, or try strace? It might be something like SE-Linux permission issue, since I guess your 64-bit kernel is pretty new. Or simplest did you libc has right (file) permission flags?

Comment: Yup, I guess my libs has right permisssions.                                -rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 906980 Feb  6 01:04 libc-2.19.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu     12 Feb  6 21:19 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions for those libraries.  You will probably find that you dont have permissions to read the files or the directories they are in if you are not root.

Comment: No, those libraries do have read and execute permissions. Infact, I even changed permissions of the whole directory - chmod -R 777 /lib/arm*  . Still see the same error

Comment: These two links say that you need exec perms on the /tmp directory. http://admin-ahead.com/portal/knowledgebase/4/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libzso1-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-Operation-not-permitted.html    http://www.exelisvis.com/Support/HelpArticles/TabId/185/ArtMID/800/ArticleID/4353/4353.aspx

Comment: Well my /tmp has exec permissions. I think this has nothing to do with that

Comment: Check out the command ldconfig(8).  This checks your libraries and links to shared libraries and make sure things are ok.  A bunch of posts online say to give it a try.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig

Comment: Whoops, I just realized that you created your own 32bit install on a 64bit machine.  Check out the command ldd.  This will show you the library dependency tree.  Since you are trying to link 32 bit on 64 bit os, you might have a number of links to handle.  You might need to reference a 32 bit install to check to see if you have all the needed dependencies on the 64bit installation.

Comment: If you look at the description, I have posted the dependency there. With sudo, I could see the dependency . Without sudo, "operation not permitted" error. Basically, all I did is to copy the 32-bit libc.so and 32-bit ld.so and try to run any 32-bit binary.

Comment: another common item popping up in posts is checking fstab to see if the /tmp dir is mounted as noexec.  Root will work, others will not.